# How can I make my navbar static from a responsive navbar?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am making a responsive navigation bar. I have made it so that global style is a toggled navigation bar and at 600px this gets reduced from 100% to 30%, but now I want it so that when it reached 1000px it becomes a static navbar without the "menu" and "menu1". A little stuck with trying to get a static navbar after 1000px. Just seems to disappear but not sure how to make it static from a toggled navbar.

Where am I going wrong?

code:

```js
function toggleNav() {
  document.getElementById("sideNav").classList.toggle('open');
}
closeNav.addEventListener('click', toggleNav);
openNav.addEventListener('click', toggleNav);
```

```css
body {
  background-color: white;
  font-family: sans-serif;
  margin: 0;
}

h1 {
  color: lightpink;
  font-size: 40px;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 30px;
}

nav {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: stretch;
  text-align: center;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  top: 0; /* Stay at the top */
  left: -100%;
  position: fixed;
  z-index: 1; /* Stay on top */
  background-color: white;
  overflow-x: hidden;
  transition: 2s;
  opacity: 0.5;
  padding: 2px;
}

nav .menu, .menu1 {
  text-align: right;
}

nav.open {
  left: 0;
  cursor: pointer;
  font-size: 40px;
  align-content: right;
  opacity: 1;
}

nav a, .menu, .menu1 {
  padding: 0.25em 0.5em;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 25px;
  color: pink;
  display: block;
  transition: 2s;
}

.menu {
  top: 0;
}

a {
  transition: 2s ease ;
  padding: 2px;
}

main {
  width: 85%
  padding: 0px 30px;
}

/* Tablet nav bar */
@media only screen and (min-width: 600px) {

  nav {
    width: 30%;
  }

}

@media only screen and (min-width: 1000px) {
  body {
    margin: 1em auto;
  }

  nav {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
    justify-content: space-evenly;
    align-items: stretch;
    height: 5%;
    width: 100%;
  }

  a:hover {
    background-color: blanchedalmond;
  }

  .menu1, .menu {
    display: none;
  }

}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Cake Shop</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/styles.css">
  </head>
  <body>
    <header>
      <span class="menu" id="openNav">&#9776;</span>
      <nav id="sideNav">
        <span class="menu1" id="closeNav">&times;</span>
        <a href="index.html">Home</a>
        <a href="recipes.html">Recipes</a>
        <a href="ingredients.html">Ingredients</a>
        <a href="about.html">About</a>
      </nav>
      <h1 id="something">Cakes&nbsp'n'&nbspBakes</h1>
    </header>
    <main>
      <script src="js/scripts.js"></script>
      <script src="js/index.js"></script>
    </main>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: In your 1000px media query can you just add `left:0`?

Comment: Cool effect. I'm a little confused about what you're asking. So at 1000px right now, the option to open the menu disappears, but if it's already open it stays visible and stretches. What about this would you like to change?

Comment: Thanks, @zfrisch. I want the nav bar to be static at 1000px. I don't want it to open and close at all.

Comment: @sydney y, although that worked it doesn't work when inspecting element and opening the nav bar at <500px then going up to > 1000px

Answer (score 0):

May be you should have `transition: left 2s;` in `nav` field, if i undestood you correctly

Comment: I tried this, it doesn't achieve what I want. I don't think I want it to transition. I want it to stay in one place after 1000px

Comment: So you can use css variables. Add variable `--trans: 2s;` into body, use it in nav section `transition: var(--trans);` and  then add ` --trans: 0;` into  @media rule like this: `@media only screen and (min-width: 1000px) {
    body {
      margin: 1em auto;
      --trans: 0;
    }`